# Slim Php v3 query string

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I would like to know if there is any way to define a specific controller for query strings like:

```
$app->group('/contacts', function() {
   $this->get('', 'ContactController:index');
   $this->get('?*', 'ContactSearchController:index');
});
```

I want to separate requests with search parameters into another controller like:

```
/contacts (ContactController)
/contacts?phone=123456789 *any query string (ContactSearchController)
```

it's possible?
thank you all.

Comment: Had a look at [Route.php](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Router.php#L193) and it seems Slim router passes only `path` part of the URI to the router. So I believe this won't be an easy way of doing this (i.e just by defining routes in a certain way).

Comment: I believe you are right, I have already reviewed the documentation several times and the only thing I found was with parameters

Comment: I have a similar problem, I started a feature request, maybe. https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/3261